# Disable -Wmissing-field-initializers warning in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, mingw, qt-creator, compiler-warnings, qmake

How do I disable the `-Wmissing-field-initializers` warning in Qt Creator?

I have a Qt Creator/MinGW project, and when I zero-initialize a struct:

```
void test() {
    struct foo {int a, b;};
    foo a = {};
}
```

I get this warning:

```
test.cpp:12: warning: missing initializer for member 'test()::foo::b' [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
         foo a = {};
                  ^
```

I tried this:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -Wnomissing-field-initializers
```

But there was no such option. `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS -= -Wmissing-field-initializers` didn't work, either.

The `-Wmissing-field-initializers` is not explicitly specified in the command line, actually. This is the compiler's command line:

```
g++ -c -pipe -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -g -frtti -Wall -Wextra -fexceptions -mthreads -DUNICODE -DSRCDIR=\"C:/Workspace/NewProjects/TreTest/\" -DQT_TESTLIB_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_TESTCASE_BUILDDIR=\"C:/Workspace/NewProjects/build-TreTest-Desktop_Qt_5_4_2_MinGW_32bit-Debug\" -I"..\TreTest" -I"." -I"..\..\..\Qt\5.4\mingw491_32\include" -I"..\..\..\Qt\5.4\mingw491_32\include\QtTest" -I"..\..\..\Qt\5.4\mingw491_32\include\QtCore" -I"debug" -I"..\..\..\Qt\5.4\mingw491_32\mkspecs\win32-g++"  -o debug\fuzzyregex.o ..\TreTest\fuzzyregex.cpp
```

Comment: `-Wextra` activates `-Wmissing-field-initializers` (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I had forgotten to add a dash. This worked:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -Wno-missing-field-initializers
```

I had been trying `-Wnomissing-field-initializers` (without dash), that's why I was getting an error that there is no such parameter.