# Get number by serial port

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, serial-port

I am a try get number (integer) by serial port. I use OS Windows and source is HOW TO (https://web.archive.org/web/20180127160838/http://bd.eduweb.hhs.nl/micprg/pdf/serial-win.pdf) and this (https://www.pololu.com/docs/0J73/15.6). So, i tried compile project, but get error. Code is below.

```
//Open serial port

    HANDLE hSerial;;
    hSerial = CreateFileW(QString("\\\\.\\COM1").toStdWString().c_str(), GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
    if(hSerial==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){
    if(GetLastError()==ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND){
    //serial port does not exist. Inform user.
    }
    //some other error occurred. Inform user.
    }

    //Setting Parameter

    DCB dcbSerialParams = {0};   //Error here!!!
    //dcbSerial.DCBlength=sizeof(dcbSerialParams);
    if (!GetCommState(hSerial, &dcbSerialParams)) {
    //error getting state
    }
    dcbSerialParams.BaudRate=CBR_19200;
    dcbSerialParams.ByteSize=8;
    dcbSerialParams.StopBits=ONESTOPBIT;
    dcbSerialParams.Parity=NOPARITY;
    if(!SetCommState(hSerial, &dcbSerialParams)){
    //error setting serial port state
    }

    //Read Data

    const int n = 8;

    char szBuff[n + 1] = {0};
    DWORD dwBytesRead = 0;
    if(!ReadFile(hSerial, szBuff, n, &dwBytesRead, NULL)){
    //error occurred. Report to user.
    }

    qDebug()<<dwBytesRead;

    //Close port
    CloseHandle(hSerial);
```

Framework is QT 4.8. Errors i attacment below:

```
D:\MyProject\Graph\graph.cpp:81: warning: missing field 'BaudRate' initializer
D:\MyProject\Graph\graph.cpp:81: warning: missing initializer for member '_DCB::BaudRate' [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
D:\MyProject\Graph\graph.cpp:81: warning: missing initializer for member '_DCB::fParity' [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
D:\MyProject\Graph\graph.cpp:81: warning: missing initializer for member '_DCB::fOutxCtsFlow' [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
D:\MyProject\Graph\graph.cpp:81: warning: missing initializer for member '_DCB::fOutxDsrFlow' [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
D:\MyProject\Graph\graph.cpp:81: warning: missing initializer for member '_DCB::fDtrControl' [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
```

And other errors. I know is work code, but why i get errors?

Comment: These are not errors, but warnings. Please, post full output.

Comment: I get warning, but program don't compile. If i comment this code and compile i get result is work program.

Comment: The code works for me, I think it is caused by your compiler. You need to provide more details to help us determine the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the boost library.Thus your code works cross platform.I will give a simple example below.

**serial.h**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <string>

using namespace boost::asio;
class Serial
{
private:
 io_service _io;
 serial_port _serial;
 unsigned int _BaudRate
 std::string _COM;

public:
 Serial(std::string port, unsigned int BaudRate);
 size_t  transmit(uint8_t* s,size_t len);
};
```

**serial.cpp**

```
#include "serial.h";

Serial::Serial(std::string port, unsigned int baud_rate)
        : _io(), _serial(_io, port),_COM(port),_BaudRate(baud_rate)
    {
        _serial.set_option(boost::asio::serial_port_base::baud_rate(_BaudRate));
    }

// Write to the serial device.param s to write.
size_t  ModbusClientRTU::transmit(uint8_t* s,size_t len) 
    {
       return  boost::asio::write(_serial, boost::asio::buffer(s, len));
    }
```

I gave this example to give you an idea.
If you decide to use the boost library, you can include the library in your project in visual studio by following the steps below.

1. Right click  on project and select Properties
2. Common Properties => VC++ Directories
3. Include Directories => add the directory where you installed boost libraries.
4. Library Directories => "              "    where you built     "         "     .

I hope it will help you..

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure this is the same, but this person seems to have had a similar problem also using the QT framework. They added this line and said that it fixed the problem. Below is a link to the post.

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -Wno-missing-field-initializers
```

[Disable -Wmissing-field-initializers warning in Qt Creator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35549688/disable-wmissing-field-initializers-warning-in-qt-creator?rq=1)

Comment: Silencing warnings and fixing a problem are rarely the same thing.